# How to combine sys.dm_exec_query_stats and sys.dm_tran_locks to combine the result

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Sqlserver 2005-2008 query to find out dead locks and identify query text

I have following query which can give me lock status also tells me command which causes lock

```
SELECT
    object_name(sl.resource_associated_entity_id) as 'TableName' ,
    dr.command,
    sl.*
FROM
    sys.dm_tran_locks as sl
        LEFT JOIN
        sys.dm_exec_requests dr
        ON
        sl.request_session_id=dr.session_id
WHERE
    sl.resource_type = 'OBJECT'
```

I have another query which gives me query text which is as follows

```
SELECT top 5 deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.text AS [Query],
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

but i don't know how can i combine both queries so that i can get lock transaction query. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i created this query should work.

```
 SELECT
        object_name(sl.resource_associated_entity_id) as 'TableName' ,
        dr.command, dest.text ,
        sl.*
    FROM
        sys.dm_tran_locks as sl
            LEFT JOIN
            sys.dm_exec_requests dr
            ON
            sl.request_session_id=dr.session_id

            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dr.sql_handle) AS dest

    WHERE
        sl.resource_type = 'OBJECT'
```